# Appium-perfecto iOS native application switch issue

Tags: java, selenium, appium, perfecto

Want to switch between two native apps in ios. 1 application is 3rd party app and the other one is related to Apple Health.
I am trying using below code to switch between the app:

```
public static void switchToAppleHealth(IOSDriver driver,String bundleId) throws MalformedURLException {
        ConfigurationManager.getBundle().setProperty(bundleId, "com.apple.Health");
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.iphone();
         capabilities.setCapability("bundleId", bundleId);
         System.out.println(bundleId+"################");
         driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("https://nexperience/perfectomobile/wd/hub"), capabilities);
         driver.launchApp();
         System.out.println(bundleId+"################");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately its possible for **Android platform only**.

With iOS you are limited to test only the application that you signed properly for WebDriverAgent to manipulate.